# How do I go about saving text in a text-box?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about saving multiple lines of text without stretching out my code?

It's hard to put in to words but I'll give an example of what I've done.

```
wri_name=input("What do you want to call your new file? (Extension included): ")
print("Type what you want your file to contain!: ")
wri_con1=input("1> ")
with open((wri_name), 'w') as f:
   f.writelines(["\n" + wri_con1])
```

I'm trying to make an improvement by making a text-box that is seemingly endless but can still be saved into a file. Take Microsoft Notepad as an example. I'm trying to replicate a program similar to that but I've really been scratching my head about what I could do here.

Comment: You can try using while.

Comment: @dudulu I've tried that but it saves the last word entered into the input loop

Comment: If you write in loop then you have to  open in `append mode` - `open(..., "a")` - because when you open in `write mode` then it removes previous content.. OR you should first add all elements to list and after loop write all with one `open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write in loop then you have to open in `append mode` - `open(..., "a")` - because `write mode` removes previous content.

```
filename = input("What do you want to call your new file? (Extension included): ")
print("Type what you want your file to contain!: ")

while True:
    text = input("1> ")
    
    if text.lower() == "quit":
        break
    
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
       f.write(text + "\n")
```

Or you have to open it only once

```
filename = input("What do you want to call your new file? (Extension included): ")
print("Type what you want your file to contain!: ")

# --- before loop ---

f = open(filename, 'w')

# --- loop ---

while True:
    text = input("1> ")
    
    if text.lower() == "quit":
        break
    
    f.write(text + "\n")

# --- after loop ---

f.close()
```